# associating a javascript object to an SVG element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg, d3.js

### Goal

I would like to associate a `d3.js` created SVG element to a javascript object - such that when the SVG element is made available on an event listener, I can trace back to the javascript object directly from it. This however does not seem to work out in my case as explained below.

### (Motivation)

I have lots of SVG elements each logically associated to one object that contains structured data relevant to it. That data determines what to do when the event fires for any of those SVG elements, and is different for each of them

## My Attempt

I simply add the object as a new property for the SVG element. I can see it's been added okay.
I then attach the event listener using d3's `.on` function.
And I obtain what I believe to be the SVG element on which the event is being fired by `d3.select(this)`. Indeed, I can modify the SVG attributes of it this way, as you can see when hovering the small rectangle in my codepen given below.

## The Problem

Although I can confirm that my object was added to the SVG object, when I retrieve the SVG element inside the event handler, it has everything *but* that object reference.

I reduced this problem into the code in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/matanster/pen/HdArD?editors=001) - where logging demonstrates the problem - hover the rectangle to check it out.

What am I doing wrong that results in this non-availability of the added object reference?
How should I correctly accomplish using an object reference inside the SVG element, or work-around this?

## Code description of the problem:

```
rectangle = main.append('rect')
                           .style('fill', '#0000FF')   
                           .style('stroke-width', '0px')
                           .style('fill-opacity', '1')
                           .attr('height',30)
                           .attr('width',30)
                           .attr('id', '1')

rectangle.__test__ = 'test'



rectangle.on('mouseover', function(){
  console.dir(d3.select(this))
  /* __test__ is absent.... */
  })
```

Comment: You can't store object references in a DOM -- what's saved will be a serialization into a string. It sounds like you would need a lookup table that allows you to retrieve the Javascript object for an element with a specific ID.

Comment: I am not entirely sure about that last statement. Please observe the rectangle here - http://codepen.io/matanster/pen/ujiJq?editors=001. The svg element contains a fully-workable object. I think the svg is part of the DOM as SVG is a DOM namespace. What do you make of it?

Comment: In your example it works because the object can be serialized (into JSON) and deserialized. It will not work in general (you can't do that with functions for example).

Comment: Thanks :) 
I guess the browser (or just chrome) automatically serializes and deserializes it then. That's good enough for me in this purpose in terms of coding style, although admittedly the deserialization may take the same amount of cycles as a lookup table approach.

Comment: But I still feel there's a different coding pattern that can yield the javascript data context relevant to each element a listener was triggered for. I hope someone would chime in with such a simpler pattern, that bypasses this way of stuffing an object into the SVG element! Anything simpler than a lookup table?

Comment: Well D3 does exactly the same thing already with data (where it is safe to do). You can't store behaviour (i.e. functions) in a DOM.

Comment: Can you explain why you are not using d3's data object to associate the object with the element and then retrieve it in the event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your sample code doesn't work as you expect is because `rectangle` is *not* a reference to the rectangle element, it is a reference to a d3 selection which just happens to only contain a single element.  Creating a different selection of the same element later will not give you access to a property of the initial selection.

(To get your head around it:  think of the actual `SVGRectElement` object as a library book.  That book is inside your backpack (the d3 selection referenced by `rectangle`).  You create some notes about the book (`__test__`), and also add them to your backpack.  Then you do other things, and later someone gets the same library book out and puts it in a different backpack.  For many uses, the effect is the same: a backpack containing a specific book.  If you wanted to read the book or take it to a specific class, it wouldn't matter *which* backpack it was inside of.  However, that person isn't going to be able to magically find *your* notes in *their* backpack!)

If you had done

```
rectangle.node().__test__ = "test";  
//use .node() to extract the first element from the d3 selection
//and then assign a new property value to it
```

and then

```
console.dir(this.__test__);
//`this` directly references the rectangle element,  
// which has the test property added above
```

in the event handler, it would work.

**But** you can do this much more easily by using d3 data functions to associate a data object with each element and then access it directly as the first parameter of your event handling function.  **Spend some time with [the tutorials](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials) to figure out how to get the most out of d3.**

Comment: Thanks. Here's the codpen that demonstrates the naive part of the answer. http://codepen.io/matanster/pen/eDdlF?editors=001. The reason I wasn't directly using a data object, is that out of the d3 honey I only use d3 transitions. I don't visualize data but only use d3 to control user interface assets

Comment: Let me add that I apply logic from data, and not manufacture a value for a hard-wired attribute or style that I wish to change proportionally to data. My program logic means I should change few styles/attributes one time, and few others the next. The logic doesn't fit properties to scaled data, but rather acts according to data that represents logic. So it seems like this is not really a pattern served by data binding the d3 way. I'll try binding my control data such that I can retrieve it inside the d3 moderated event listener, and see whether it feels not too convoluted. Should be fine :)

Comment: @matt  I'm not sure I *entirely* follow, but you're of course free to use as much or as little of d3 as suits your program!  If you're only manipulating existing elements (instead of creating a set of elements to match a data set), you might find it easier to use the [`.datum()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#datum) function to set and retrieve the data object.  It's usually shorter and neater than extracting the node and setting a property on it yourself if your elements are within d3 selections for other reasons.