# is the d3.js api object structure always the same

Tags: d3.js

I notice that on a d3 single element select of an SVG element, d3.js returns an object that looks like follows.

`an Array[1] containing an Array[1] containing the actual SVG element`

i.e. a two-dimensional array.

Likewise this is how the object returned from d3.append() looks like.

My question is - is this always the case? *(and can this structure be relied upon?)*

Answer (score 1):

Yes. May change in future versions though I guess.

Comment: Thanks this helps with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869457/associating-a-javascript-object-to-an-svg-element

Comment: That said, there's probably a better way of getting what you want without indexing into the selection. I would consider this quite hacky.

Comment: Yes, still trying to figure what that way would be. But let's keep that discussion directly at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869457/associating-a-javascript-object-to-an-svg-element if we can. This question was useful to know anyway and thanks for the answer!